# Power BI: Assign measure value to calculate column

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot

assign measure value to calculated column

I have created two tables:

[image][image]

User can see green field as slicer in sheet and on select, i have created measure in id_indicator table,

Measure will take one value, that user selects from slicer

Measure 5 = if(COUNTROWS('Input_Threshold') = 1, sum('Input_Threshold'[Green]), BLANK())

I want to assign ([measure 5]  * [by_hour]) to field calculated but it is not working, giving black (I tried calculated = [measure 5] but still not working)
Is it possibe to assign measure value to calculated column?

Below it says measure5 has value 60
[image]

But while at assigning column values it takes blank value as 'else' part says.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it is possible to assign measure to the calculated column.
The measure in such a case will be evaluated in row context applicable for every row of this calculated column.

The measure however needs to be accessible. Therefore it must be defined in table to which you are adding calculated column, or defined in the table accessible through a relationship.

Create simple example:

```
TestMeasure = 7
CalculatedColumn = 7 * id_indicator
```

Edit (after OP updated question):

**Calculated objects (calc tables and calc columns) are not affected by slicers.** Calculated objects are static therefore you cannot alter calculated object results through slicers.

Comment: Hi, But when we select measure value from slicer selection, that is measure 5 = if(COUNTROWS('Input_Threshold') = 1, sum('Input_Threshold'[Green]), BLANK()) and calulated column value calculated = [measure 5] * id_indicator, it will give blank however measure 5 has value that is selected by user.

Comment: Ohh I see the problem! Calculated objects are not affected by slicers. Calculated objects are static therefore you cannot alter calculated object results through slicers (which are dynamic).

Comment: could you please suggest any solution? Thanks,

Comment: You have to create what you need with measures only, so it will be affected by slicers.